# Регулярные выражения, значения между символами, второе вхождение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть выражение вида:

### *'апельсин оранжевый и "желтый" апельсин и еще "такой" красный как яблоко и "еще" зеленый как груша, зеленое'*

Нужно построить три регулярных выражения, что бы извлечь слова между кавычками:

1. желтый 2. такой 3. еще

Что бы это сработало в сервисе https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Достать группу выражений в кавычках можно с помощью выражения '`.*?`', а как из группы вытащить, например второй элемент "такой" с помощью регулярки без дополнительного языка программирования не получается. Это вообще возможно?

Comment: *без дополнительного языка программирования* - а как насчёт основного? В чём работаете? Может, достаточно "захватить" эти значения в группу/подмаску? `^(?:[^"]*"[^"]+"){2}[^"]*"([^"]+)"`

Comment: В GrayLog хотел распарсить фалы там просто есть строка для ввода регулярного выражения.

Comment: Проверьте, работают ли `^[^"]*"[^"]+"[^"]*"[^"]+"[^"]*"([^"]+)"`, `^[^"]*"[^"]+"[^"]*"([^"]+)"`, `^[^"]*"([^"]+)"`

Answer (score 0):

В регулярных выражениях можно использовать обычный текст. Т.е. вы можете найти *"такой"* используя регулярное выражение `"такой"`.

Можно использовать подмаски: `^.*?".*?".*?(".*?")`.

Можно использовать позитивный просмотр назад: `(?<=".{0,100}".{0,100})".*?"`. Но он не любит неограниченные проверки поэтому вместо `.*` в зависимости от необходимости нужно использовать большие промежутки: `.{0,100}`.